# Swift & FirebaseIO query filtering not finding child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

My app uses a barcode scanner (1D-3D) to get a code/tag, then validate it against my FirebaseIO and return as valid/invalid if found/not found. 
The scanning works and console can print the tag nr everytime, although I cant figure out how to find that nr back in the Firebase?

```
self.tapHandler = { point in            print(point)                    self.barcodesHandler = { barcodes in                for barcode in barcodes {                    print(barcode.stringValue ?? "")                    let tags = barcode.stringValue                                        let query = dbref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Tag").queryEqual(toValue: tags)                    query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in                for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {                    print("tag is ")                    print(childSnapshot)                }            })
```

and my firebase structure (where Tag is the lookup field)
'''

```
{
  "members" : {
    "4b4ac23c9f184ce8b31fde011cd3a696" : {
      "Tag" : 82644,
      "Title" : "Mr",
      "Uid" : 80,
      "Username" : "orange"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it. 
Rookie error, data was saved as string and and lookup was for int.